# Is using DecimalFormat too much for simple float truncation?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I suddenly had a need to just chop off the excessive digits off of a float number, so I looked in the toolbox and saw that `DecimalFormat` was available.

Though creating a new object just to chop off some extra digits off a number seemed rather expensive, so I threw together a small program to test it.

```
public class Snippet {

    static float unformatted = -542.347543274623876F;
    static int fractionDigits = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        long a = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(stringMethod(unformatted));
        long b = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(formatMethod(unformatted));
        long c = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(stringMethod2(unformatted));
        long d = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("OP1:"+(b-a));
        System.out.println("OP2:"+(c-b));
        System.out.println("OP3:"+(d-c));

    }

    private static float stringMethod(float number){
        String unfStr = String.valueOf(number);
        for(int i=0;i<unfStr.length();i++){
            if(unfStr.charAt(i) == '.'){
                return Float.parseFloat(unfStr.substring(0, i+1+fractionDigits));
            }
        }
        return Float.parseFloat(unfStr);
    }

    private static float stringMethod2(float number){
        String unfStr = String.format("%."+(fractionDigits+1)+"f",number);
        return Float.parseFloat(unfStr.substring(0,unfStr.length()-1));
    }

    private static float formatMethod(float number){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(fractionDigits);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        return Float.parseFloat(df.format(unformatted));
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
-542.34
-542.34
-542.34
OP1:1937181
OP2:32609426
OP3:3111908
```

No matter how many times I run it, the `DecimalFormat` method just can't keep up.

So I guess the question here is, is there any reason (apart from code readability) to use `DecimalFormat` instead of creating your own method for simple float truncation?

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Comment: Are you **sure** you should be using float rather than BigDecimal? Note that once you do your parseFloat, there really are extra decimal places, even if you don't always see them. The closest float to -542.34 is  -542.34002685546875.

Comment: Your benchmarks are irrelevant - even in a non-JIT compiled  language you need to run a few thousand iterations; in a JIT compiled language, things are more ... complicated. Moreover, creating a `DecimalFormat` isn't free - do that once, outside of the benchmarked code.

Comment: Your declaration itself is flawed. `-542.347543274623876F` is equal to `-542.34753` and even using double isn't enough, since `-542.347543274623876d` is equal to `-542.3475432746238`. You need more precision if any of this is going to be accurate. Example here: http://ideone.com/wIhBpL

Comment: You only have two choices: `DecimalFormat` or `BigDecimal`. You won't convince me that decimal formatting is a rate-determining step in your application.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Don't forget to select an answer so the question can be closed. Or did that not answer it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a numerical way to do it:

```
double d = -542.347543274623876;
System.out.println(d);
int n = 2; // decimal digits

double p = Math.pow(10,n);
d = Math.floor((int)(p*d))/p;
System.out.println(d);
```

Try it here: http://ideone.com/wIhBpL

What it does, it to multiply it by 10 times the number of decimal digits you want, convert it to an integer (which chops off the remaining digits), then convert it back to a decimal by dividing by 10 times the number of decimal digits. It should work for `float`, too, if you use that instead.

Comment: This is of course assuming that your `double` or `float` can actually _hold_ the value with two decimal places - which may well not be the case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, the OP says it's a `float`, and if it starts as a floating point, then since it ends with less precision, it will end fitting within a floating point number. I showed it with a `double`, since the OP's first assignment statement resulted in a large loss of precision.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, The question does not request arbitrary precision, so why use a string?